# Mindstorms, black orphaned data wires

Tags: mindstorms, ev3

I've just copied a loop element, which had a data wire going into it.

The internal wires (from the old external data wire) are now black, and I cannot delete them, or re-link them to a new external data wire.

They just don't seem to be selectable any more.

Can anybody give me an clues how I can do anything with them?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have discovered a bug. You should report it using Help > Give Feedback.

For working around the problem, the only thing I know to do is to cut the blocks with the black wires and then paste them back in. This seems to get rid of the black wires.

Comment: Thanks @David, yes, I also discovered the cut/paste of the blocks removes the black wires.  Will let them know.

Answer (score 0):

I also discovered the cut/ paste works, but sometimes if you disconnect the block from the loop and then put it back in that works too.